# Create button in Powerpoint 2013 ribbon that opens a hyperlink

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'd like to create a button that automatically opens a hyperlink from Powerpoint.

It's easy enough to create a hyperlink in Powerpoint (Insert -> Hyperlink) and then click on that hyperlink.

I want to skip this whole process and just be able to have a button that opens a hyperlink rather than having a hyperlink in my presentation that needs to be clicked.

Comment: If you have a button, you will still need to click it to open the hyperlink.  Are you saying you want to open a link moving to another slide automatically or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML for the button would be something like:

```
                    <button id="myButton" label="Open Hyperlink" 
                        imageMso="HyperlinkInsert"
                        size="large" 
                        onAction="openHyperlink"
                        />
```

Of course you will need to modify the file's Ribbon XML; the above is not a complete ribbon, just the node for the desired button.  I have some other Q&A about modifying the ribbon [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1467082+ribbon) otherwise there are some great examples if you google for them.  Most are for Word or Excel, but the same principles apply. If you need references, let me know and I can provide a few.

And the callback would be like:

```
Sub openHyperlink(control As IRibbonControl)
    'your code that opens the hyperlink goes in here, something like:
    Dim ie as Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate "http://google.com"

End Sub
```

To open a PDF instead of a browser, change that procedure:

```
Sub openHyperlink(control As IRibbonControl)

    Dim acroPath As String
    Dim filePath As String

    acroPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"  'Modify as needed
    filePath = "c:\users\me\file.pdf"  'Modify as needed

    Shell acroPath & " " & filePath, vbNormalFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: THANK YOU! this works great! One modification, how would I make it open in Chrome? Also, is there a way to have it link to a PDF?

Comment: I've not attempted any automation of the Chrome browser but may be possible using the [selenium vba plug-in](https://code.google.com/p/selenium-vba/).  To open a file (like a PDF) I know it could be done using a Shell command, I'll add that in my answer above.

Comment: woah. the pdf solution is awesome. Is there any way to detect the default pdf-reader application and to go there? I'm intending for other people to be able to use my toolbar and would rather they didn't have to specify a path for the adobe reader.

Comment: The path should be the same, assuming the same operating system. If you have to account for different OS, then you need conditional logic to do so, e.g., `If Application.Version = 14.0 ` (for 2010) or `... 12.0` for 2007, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ShellExecute API to open any document in the default app for that document's extension.  Here's a simplified hack to start with:

```
Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
                   (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpszOp As String, _
                    ByVal lpszFile As String, ByVal lpszParams As String, _
                    ByVal LpszDir As String, ByVal FsShowCmd As Long) _
                    As Long

Function ShellEx(sFile As String) As Long
    ShellEx = ShellExecute(&O0, "Open", sFile, "", "C:\", 1)
End Function

Sub Test()
    Debug.Print ShellEx("path to file goes here")
End Sub
```

More detailed version with all the options here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170918